# Check for similarities within a single cell

Tags: excel, vba, range

Does anyone knows how to higlight similar words within a single cell?
What I want to achieve is to find duplicates/similar words between   < ; >  in a cell.

example cell:

```
home;music;car;window;musician
```

desired result:

**music in a word musician is hilglighted or the output is 'TRUE' in the next column if similar word like this has been found.**

I was able to compare words between two columns but not within single cell.

So far I was able to create a formula to separate the words in the cell to have each range separate to work with.

```
Function IdDuplicates(rng As Range) As String
Dim StringtoAnalyze As Variant
Dim I As Integer
Dim J As Integer
Const minWordLen As Integer = 4
StringtoAnalyze = Split(UCase(rng.Value), ";")
For I = UBound(StringtoAnalyze) To 0 Step -1
If Len(StringtoAnalyze(I)) < minWordLen Then GoTo SkipA
For J = 0 To I - 1
If StringtoAnalyze(J) = StringtoAnalyze(I) Then
IdDuplicates = "TRUE"
GoTo SkipB
End If
Next J
SkipA:
Next I
IdDuplicates = "FALSE"
SkipB:
End Function
```

Any ideas?

Comment: When is something considered to be 'similar'? What about 'bad' and 'baby'? They both start with 'ba'. It's rather arbitrary now.

Comment: I don't see it like a very big problem. Let's say it can also mark the word baby as a similar. For hundreds of records in my case the automation should higlight something between 10-20 to check and this is what i want to achieve here.

Comment: But it is a big problem because where does the arbitrarity stop? Is 'Example' similar to 'Exceptional' because they both start with 'Ex'"And is 'Hello' similar to 'World' because they both contain an 'o'? Without you defining *exactly* what you consider "similar", it's going to be anyones guess.

Comment: I see your point here. Let's say it should consider somthing as similar if the first 3 letters are the same. How to aproach from this point?

Comment: Well, what version of Excel are you using? It could be done through formula. In any case, you should update the post with this information and your requirements and it's best to add your own attempt at solving the issue too.

Comment: version is 1808

Comment: I meant; Excel 2016, 2019, 365? or anything like that.

Comment: the version is 2019

Answer (score 1):

This function returns either FALSE or a list of the similar words

```vb
Option Explicit

Function IdDuplicates(rng As Range) As String

    Dim s As String, word, m As Object, i As Long
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = True
        s = Trim(rng.Value2)
        For Each word In Split(s, ";")
            .Pattern = word
            Set m = .Execute(s)
            If m.Count > 1 Then
                IdDuplicates = IdDuplicates & "," & word
            End If
        Next
    End With
    If IdDuplicates = "" Then
        IdDuplicates = "FALSE"
    Else
        IdDuplicates = Mid(IdDuplicates, 2) ' remove lead ,
    End If
   
End Function
```

Comment: working great! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

### Match Partially in Delimited String

```vb
Option Explicit

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns a boolean indicating whether any of the substrings
'               in a delimited string is contained in another substring.
' Example:      'music;car;musician' - 'music' is found in 'musician' - TRUE
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function MatchPart( _
    ByVal DelimitedString As Variant, _
    Optional ByVal StringDelimiter As String = ";") _
As Boolean
    
    Dim S As String: S = CStr(DelimitedString)
    Dim Substrings() As String
    Substrings = Split(DelimitedString, StringDelimiter)
    Dim sUpper As Long: sUpper = UBound(Substrings)
    If sUpper < 1 Then Exit Function
    
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, iPos As Long
    Dim iSub As String, jSub As String
    
    For i = 0 To sUpper - 1
        iSub = Substrings(i)
        For j = i + 1 To sUpper
            jSub = Substrings(j)
            'Debug.Print i, iSub, j, jSub
            If Len(iSub) <= Len(jSub) Then
                If InStr(1, jSub, iSub, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                    MatchPart = True
                    Exit Function
                End If
            Else
                If InStr(1, iSub, jSub, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                    MatchPart = True
                    Exit Function
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

End Function
```

Comment: also works fine! thanks!